# 502 Bad Gateway - Rails App, Puma, Capistrano, Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, puma

I'm getting a 'Connection Refused' error when attempting to deploy my rails app. This is the message I get from `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2020/01/03 20:40:44 [error] 8059#8059: *69 connect() to unix:/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.189.176.208, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/500.html"
```

After running `cap production deploy`, puma web server listens to a socket, but when I access the IP address of my Ubuntu EC2 Instance I get a nginx `502 Bad Gateway` message.

I have tried `cap production deploy:restart` on local machine, restarting nginx on the server, and making sure the sock file location is correct, but to no avail. The error log is not very helpful, so I was wondering how I could diagnose this problem? I have included some configuration files and would appreciate any tips.

puma.rb

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked web server processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
# preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

deploy.rb

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.11.2"

set :default_shell, '/bin/bash -l'
set :puma_conf, "/var/www/blog/shared/config/puma.rb"
set :application, "blog"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:st4rgut22/blog.git"
set :linked_files, %w{config/master.key}
# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/blog"
set :user_sudo, true
set:branch, 'master'
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails puma pumactl}

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default (on deploy target)

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/blog/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

/var/www/blog/shared/config/puma.rb (on deploy target)

```
# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 2

# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
#bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"
bind "unix:/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (on deploy target)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#
```

Comment: Do you happen to have migrations that need to be run by chance?  What is the output locally if you run `rails s`

Comment: i get this output locally: `=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000`

Comment: I am able to see my website locally at `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two puma config files, in the first one you've specified a port instead of a socket. Does it affect the production environment?

```
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
```

Please double check that the socket file, as well as the puma process, exists after a deploy.

```
ps ax|grep puma
ls -la /var/www/blog/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

If so have a look at the puma's and application's log files

### Update after the discussion in the comments below:

It turned out that there is no puma process after a deployment. The puma's log files were empty too. That's why we decided to try run it manually on the server by going to the applications root path `/var/www/blog/current` and executing

```
bundle exec puma -b /var/www/blog/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

The result was a permission error shown on the STDOUT. So the problem disappeared after we fixed log and pid files location in `/var/www/blog/shared/config/puma.rb` as follows:

```
stdout_redirect "/var/www/shared/logs/puma.stdout.log", "/var/www/shared/logs/puma.stderr.log", true

pidfile "/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid" 
state_path "/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
```

Comment: I discovered that local `puma.rb` file is not doing anything. Removing it had no effect. I think I need to setup puma to listen on port 3000  and pass request from nginx to puma

Comment: it seems puma is not configured correctly on the server end, because I can access my website locally. The sock file exists, and `cap production deploy` outputs `Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000`

Comment: Another thing that I've noticed is that in your `deploy.rb`  you have not added `puma.conf` into the linked_files `set :linked_files, %w{config/master.key}`. This may be the answer of why puma is still listening on port 3000 even after you deleted the first config file. Can you confirm that `/var/www/blog/shared/config/puma.rb` exists?

Comment: yes, it exists and sets the port/socket the server listens to (port 3000)

Comment: Have you tried to point the nginx's proxy to `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000` instead to the socket

Comment: In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` I have set location of app to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` and `upstream app {
    server unix:/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}} ` and in `/var/www/blog/shared/config/puma.rb` I have specified `port         ENV['PORT'] || 3000`. I think my misunderstanding of how puma/nginx interacts is causing my problem

Comment: I think you can completely remove the `upstream app` part of the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` as well as to change `location @app` to `location /`. For example https://pastebin.com/f6ZBNnCE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205336/discussion-between-vladimir-dimitrov-and-st4rgut).

Comment: I have solved the issue with your help. The root of the problem was the permissions error for puma logging due to incorrect logging/pids location in /var/www/blog/shared/config/puma.rb. Now my log paths are `stdout_redirect "/var/www/shared/logs/puma.stdout.log", "/var/www/shared/logs/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/var/www/blog/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"`. After deploying with new paths, I restart nginx and server showed website. If you could include this info in ur answer I will accept it. Thanks!